# How do I solve Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only. The column is already a date

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I've been trying to create a plot using ggplot but I keep getting the above error even though when I query what class of what the column is, its already "date"

Below is a section of my script

```
start_date = as.Date("2017-01-01")
end_date = as.Date("2017-12-31")
8Range=8Output[8Output$Date_Recorded7 >=start_date&8Output$Date_Recorded7 <= end_date,]
8Range$Date_Recorded7 = as.Date(8Range$Date_Recorded7)

#Create Graph
8RangePlot = ggplot(8Range, aes(RECORDED_DATE,RECORDED_VALUE)) +
  geom_line(na.rm=TRUE) +  
  ggtitle("Range8P2") +
  xlab("Date") + ylab("Value") +
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format ("%b %y")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold", 
                              size = 20)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=18))
ggsave(filename = "8Range.pdf", plot = 8RangePlot)
```

Comment: R doesn't like object names that start with numbers - try removing the 8's from your object names.

Comment: I took out the numbers I still get the same error. That is a date issue. Even though the column is defined as a date

Comment: try `scale_x_date(labels=waiver())` instead and see if the error goes away

Comment: Nope. Error still there

Comment: Could you please provide an example dataset using `dput()` so that we can identify the error more clearly?

Comment: `8Range` is not a valid variable name, since it starts with a number. You can define and reference such variables using backticks (as in `\`8Range\``). I'm not sure how this code manages to run at all.

Comment: Your ggplot call references RECORDED_DATE, but your prior manipulation relates to Date_Recorded. Keep in mind that R is case-sensitive, so RECORDED_DATE is totally separate from Recorded_Date, not to mention from Date_Recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out in the end.

```
8RangePlot = ggplot(8Range, aes(RECORDED_DATE,RECORDED_VALUE)
```

Recorded_Date and Recorded_Value were in reverse order. For some reason when the script calculated the range, it switched what was X and what was Y in comparison to the entire Period of Record.